# Regional mapping bookmarks wiki

Tags: discussion, regional

This question — [What are the most useful or interesting cycling-related websites or blogs?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/what-are-the-most-useful-or-interesting-cycling-related-websites-or-blogs) — links to two regional bike map sites  one for [Cambridge](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/what-are-the-most-useful-or-interesting-cycling-related-websites-or-blogs/1184#1184) and one for [New Jersey](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/what-are-the-most-useful-or-interesting-cycling-related-websites-or-blogs/1194#1194).

The reason Stack Exchange discourages regional questions is because they would be less useful to the majority of users. Is it possible for us to maintain a list somewhere of regional bike route planning links? We'd want to keep this out of the Q&A part of the site, of course, but maybe we could maintain a wiki on the side.

Discuss, please. Is someone already doing this? Does anyone here know how we could set up a wiki simply and easily, as a test for this? What other regional issues/questions could this be applied to? Is this a potential monster to maintain? Would it be easier to set up a group tagging setup in Delicious or another social bookmarking site?

Comment: We can easily make a "community wiki" post, which is an awful lot like a wiki...

Comment: The Cambridge link is also useful to a lot of people outside of Cambridge as it has lots of content on road design etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think just having a question for cover each (large) region is good enough, there is no need to make it too complex.

Comment: I'd like to see the question split into various regions

Answer (score 0):

Sites like Sheldon Brown's and CycleStreets are popular because they aren't tied to any region in-particular. Sustrans is an example of an useful UK only site, particually useful to UK cyclists but doesn't get the attention it deserves (only 3 upvotes) because the majority of visitors are American, Canadian, Austrailian etc...

> The reason Stack Exchange discourages
>   regional questions is because they
>   would be less useful to the majority
>   of users.

It wouldn't be less useful to the majority, they wouldn't have to scan through all the regional sites/blogs

Comment: Feel free to start one of these for England, I'll make it CW, and please do tag it [reference](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference). Maybe set it up like [the bike sharing thread](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/167/bike-sharing-services-and-systems), with each answer as a sub-region?

Comment: I'm not sure how to phrase the question without taking too much away from the original author. What does CW mean?

Comment: CW = Community Wiki. No reputation is gained or lost when these questions/answers are upvoted/downvoted, and anyone with a rep of 100 or over can edit them. On this site, we've used CW for the general [reference](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/167/bike-sharing-services-and-systems) and [glossary](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index) questions. Try writing it in a general way, and others can modify and amplify the wording. Feel free to copy wording if you think it'll work.

Comment: I've set up the question, there are some decent regional awnsers on the original question that I'd like to use but I don't feel like I should copy their awnsers, is it possible to move them? http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3905/what-are-the-most-useful-or-interesting-regional-cycling-related-websites

Comment: What region does this question cover? Is this meant to be for England, or just regional in general? Have a look at [Ian's answer](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/120/regional-mapping-bookmarks-wiki/123#123).

Comment: While copying content is fine on Stack Exchange sites--since everything here is under a Creative Commons license--if there's a lot of content that would work in this question, maybe this one needs to be differentiated from that one more. You can just use the link as part of a new answer, talking more about the mapping and routing features of the site. There's no reason the site can't be an answer on both questions. (Also, mods don't have the ability to move answers to another question, sorry.)